# How to call controller function from view file(from dropdown of onchange attribute)?

Tags: php, laravel-5

This is my code:

```
<select style="background-color: #ffffa0" name="country" onChange=""> 
            <option value="">---select country--</option> 
        <?php  
             $rows=DB::table('country')->get();
             foreach ($rows as $row)
             {
                   echo "<option value='$row->id'> $row->country </option>";    
             }         
         ?>
    </select>
```

How to call function of controller from onChange?

Comment: Why don't you use `ajax` instead for fullfiling your requirements

Comment: I want to put logic in controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <html> <select style="background-color: #ffffa0" name="country" id="country"> 
            <option value="">---select country--</option> 
        <?php  
             $rows=DB::table('country')->get();
             foreach ($rows as $row)
             {
                   echo "<option value='$row->id'> $row->country </option>";    
             }         
         ?>
    </select>
    </html>

    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
$('#country').change(function(){

        var country=$('#country').val();

        $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "AA/BB", // path to function
        cache: false,               
        data: { country: country},
        success: function(val){                     
        try{     
        }catch(e) {     
            alert('Exception while request..');
        }   

        },
        error: function(){                      
            alert('Error while request..');
        }

            });
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What is base_url and lm_val ?

Comment: thats base_url is path to function and lm_val(val) is after returning value from that function @rupal

Comment: But i want to call function of controller in laravel 5

Comment: Base_url can't call function of controller

Comment: can you please elaborate the logic what do in controller. @rupal

Comment: controller code:                                                                   function getState($id)
    {
         $rows=DB::table('state')->where('countryid','$id')->get();
         foreach ($rows as $row)
         {
               echo "<option value='$row->id'> $row->statename </option>";    
         }
    }

Comment: I want to call getState method of controller from onChange of dropdown.when country is select it call getstate method of controller.

Comment: post route so your new route is Route::post('/controller/getState', array('uses' => 'Controller@getState')');so now you ajax request will look some what like this

$.ajax({
    url: "/controller/getState",
    type: "post",
    data: {field_name :'data'}
 });
 
 in getstate()
 $id = Input::post('country');